# if/then loop within column

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'm looking to run an if else sequence in r, but within each column over an entire dataframe. For example.

If `rmet_1 = 1`, I'll need it replaced with `-2.68347`.

But, if `rmet_1 = 2`,  it will be replaced with `-2.503847`.

Each question/column has four possible choices, and there are 36 columns total.
I'm imagining it would be run as a loop, but it is within column vs entire dataframe that makes it more difficult for me to figure out how to code. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

We don't need a `if/else` condition.  it can be done with a named vector to match and replace the values in each of the columns.  The below code loop over the columns (`lapply`) and match the key/value vector with the values of the column.

```
nm1 <- setNames(c(-2.68347, -2.503847, -2.35, -2.65), 1:4)
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) nm1[as.character(x)])
```

If the elements are 1 to 4, then we don't even need a named vector, i.e. just pass a vector in the order and make use of the position index

```
df1[] <- c(-2.68347, -2.503847, -2.35, -2.65)[as.matrix(df1)]
```

---

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:4, 10 * 4, replace = TRUE), ncol = 4))
```

Comment: This is applying the new values over my whole dataset, instead of just the columns I want. Any tips?

Comment: @SarahBerretta Just subset the columns of interest i.e. `df1[1:5] <- c(-2.68347, -2.503847, -2.35, -2.65)[as.matrix(df1[1:5])]` if you want only the first 5 columns